# Create tensors where all elements up to a given index are 1s, the rest are 0s

Tags: tensorflow, mask, tensor, one-hot-encoding

I have a placeholder `lengths = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [10])`. Each of the 10 values assigned to this placeholder are <= 25. I now want to create a 2-dimensional tensor, called `masks`, of shape [10, 25], where each of the 10 vectors of length 25 has the first `n` elements set to `1`, and the rest set to `0` - with `n` being the corresponding value in `lengths`.

What is the easiest way to do this using TensorFlow's built in methods?

For example:

```py
lengths = [4, 6, 7, ...]

-> masks = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, ..., 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, ..., 0],
            ...
           ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape lengths to a (10, 1) tensor, then compare it with another sequence/indices `0,1,2,3,...,25`, which due to broadcasting will result in *True* if the indices are smaller then lengths, otherwise *False*; then you can cast the boolean result to `1` and `0`:

```py
lengths = tf.constant([4, 6, 7])
n_features = 25
​
import tensorflow as tf
​
masks = tf.cast(tf.range(n_features) < tf.reshape(lengths, (-1, 1)), tf.int8)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(masks))

#[[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
# [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
# [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```